# R geom_text with dodged barplot with xaxis date

Tags: r, date, bar-chart, geom-text

I try to add text as in Position geom_text on dodged barplot But it doesn't work with a xaxis Date within ggplot:

```
Data<-as.data.frame(             
  cbind( 
    as.POSIXct(c("2017-06-26", "2017-06-26" ,"2017-06-26" ,"2017-07-14", "2017-07-14",
    "2017-07-14", "2017-07-14" ,"2017-07-14", "2017-09-14", "2017-09-14"),origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT"),
  c("CHLOROPHYTA","CYANOBACTERIA","INDETERMINES","BACILLARIOPHYTA","CHLOROPHYTA", "CYANOBACTERIA" ,   
    "HAPTOPHYTA","HETEROKONTOPHYTA","CHLOROPHYTA","CYANOBACTERIA" ),
  c(29,8637,3233,97,2816, 63721,282, 18,2001,76593)))
  colnames(Data)<-c("Date","Embranchement","NbCel")

  Data$Date<-as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(Data$Date)), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")

  my_plot<-
    ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Date, y=NbCel, fill=Embranchement,width=1150000)) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=NbCel), vjust=1.6, color="black",
              position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
    scale_x_discrete(labels = Data$Date) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")#+
  #axis(1,at=Data$Date,labels = Data$Date)
  print(my_plot)
```

What I get is :

[image]

How do I add text in the middle of each bar?

One additional question is how do I add each x thick mark for each date ?

Thanks!

Comment: In the middle vertically or horizontally?

Comment: After some reflexion, I think at the top of each bar, corresponding value, is the best. Thanks

Comment: @YannG I added an update of the facets graph at the bottom of my answer, please have look.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you want to achieve in detail, but here are my 2 cents. You could use the following code:

Your first problem is that `NbCel` is a **factor** and is not numeric. You can easily see that on the Y-axis on your graph.

```
# convert NbCel from factor to integer 
Data$NbCel <- as.integer(as.character(Data$NbCel))
```

Having fixed this,  we work with the graph itself.

The X-axis is a mixture of "date" information an "embranchement". Maybe it is better to separate out those two in different panels (facets) using `facet_wrap`.

```
# use a facet-wrap (separate plots in one graph)

ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Embranchement, y=NbCel, fill=Embranchement)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~Date ,  ncol = 3)   +         ### plot per date
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  geom_text(aes(label=NbCel, group = Embranchement), vjust=-.5, color="black",
            position = position_dodge(width = 10), size=2.5) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1, size = 6))  # make X labels readible
```

[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

### ADDITION

Again, you want to combine different bars from "embranchement" and different "dates" on the X-axis. A more natural thing to do in this case might be a line graph, this way you can superimpose frequency information concerning different data points on 1 date.

Your dataset is not full, i.e. not every date contains all "embranchements".

```
# indicates measurement not available on every date, hence no lines
with(Data, table(Embranchement, Date))
Embranchement      2017-06-26 2017-07-14 2017-09-14
  BACILLARIOPHYTA           0          1          0
  CHLOROPHYTA               1          1          1
  CYANOBACTERIA             1          1          1
  HAPTOPHYTA                0          1          0
  HETEROKONTOPHYTA          0          1          0
  INDETERMINES              1          0          0
```

Assuming that absent readings are null-readings, I filled up the dataset, yielding `Data2`:

```
Data2 <- rbind(Data, 
               data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-06-26", format="%Y-%m-%d"), Embranchement = "BACILLARIOPHYTA", NbCel = 0),
               data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-06-26", format="%Y-%m-%d"), Embranchement = "HAPTOPHYTA", NbCel = 0),
               data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-06-26", format="%Y-%m-%d"), Embranchement = "HETEROKONTOPHYTA", NbCel = 0),
               data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-07-14", format="%Y-%m-%d"), Embranchement = "INDETERMINES", NbCel = 0),
               data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-09-14", format="%Y-%m-%d"), Embranchement = "BACILLARIOPHYTA", NbCel = 0),
               data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-09-14", format="%Y-%m-%d"), Embranchement = "HAPTOPHYTA", NbCel = 0),
               data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-09-14", format="%Y-%m-%d"), Embranchement = "HETEROKONTOPHYTA", NbCel = 0),
               data.frame(Date = as.Date("2017-09-14", format="%Y-%m-%d"), Embranchement = "INDETERMINES", NbCel = 0)
               )
```

Now we may create a line graph:

```
ggplot(data=Data2, aes(x=Date, y=NbCel, col=Embranchement, linetype =Embranchement) ) +
  geom_line( size=1.1  ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  geom_text(aes(label=NbCel), vjust=-.75, color="black", size=2.5)
```

Yielding the following graph, with "date" on X-axis and a line per "Embranchement".

[image]

Even if this isn't what you want, I hope it helps you.

### ADDITION 2 (recap of facets but better)

(this answer needs editing, later ;-)

Try this code to get clean numbers on the bars in the facets.
The most important change is in `geom_text`: `position_dodge`

```
ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Embranchement, y=NbCel, fill=Embranchement)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~Date ,  ncol = 3)   +         ### plot per date
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  theme_light() +
  geom_text(aes(label=NbCel, group = Embranchement), vjust=-.5, color="black",
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), size=2.5) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1, size = 6))
```

You will get this graph:

[image]

I think this is closer to what you want. Let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I do know this trick but what I would like is to compare this figure with other time related figure. And so, have the same x axis scale. However, the placement of text in this figure is what I want, but on a date related x axis, like in my posted figure...if possible. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Some defaults of this representation is that it could suppose some datas between the points and that the number are less legible, as they're could be stacked due to values of same order (as we could see in your  ""date" on X-axis and a line per "Embranchement"" figure). That's why I would like a data representation more likely to a mix between your facet_wrap figure and my figure... Hope it could be done.  I already think of this line representation way as an alternative with a break on the y-axis in order to have a better legibility for the smaller values. Thanks

Comment: Thanks to this upgrade way of data representation figure. It's well legible :-) . In lack of a x-axis date solution, like I hoped, I think I'll go with this way of plot. Thanks for your help. I'm planning to add a y-axis break on this plot. I'll try to add my final solution in this comment.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck to you ;-)

Comment: @YannG: StackOverflow functions with votes. Like I voted positively on your question (this increases your reputation) because I believe it is a well formulated and interesting question, you are free to vote on the  answers, either by voting (up and down arrows) or by selecting it as the right answer, below the voting buttons. For more information see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)**

Comment: Hi KoenV, sorry for the delay vote and thanks again for your help. I've got lot of work now but I'll try to upgrade this code later on.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that NbCel is a **factor** and is not numeric. You can easily see that on the Y-axis on your graph.

```
# convert NbCel from factor to integer 
Data$NbCel <- as.integer(as.character(Data$NbCel))
```

Now after using some of the code from @KoenV, we now can

```
ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=as.character(Date), y=NbCel)) +
       geom_bar(aes(fill=Embranchement), position = position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
       scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
       geom_text(aes(label=NbCel, y = NbCel + 1200, group = Embranchement), color="black", 
                 position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)
```